# Box2D can't run testbed

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, box2d, freeglut

I ran cmake and make on Box2D with success but when I try to run the Testbed the text below is displayed in the terminal but nothing else happens.

> freeglut (./Testbed):

And after this I get back the prompt. Looks like OpenGL/freeglut is not working properly because the HelloWorld is working.

The system is ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was super simple, but I needed a sleep to solve it. I **reinstalled the graphics driver** and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I logged out and logged in again, the problem is gone.

I am using Mac. Actually I installed XQuartz to solve the problem

> 'GL/gl.h' file not found

and then running the built binary give me the error

> freeglut (./Testbed): failed to open display ''

Then I remember after installing XQuartz, there's message asking me to log out to make it take effect. And after I logging back, the built binary can run. 
:)